# iOS Push Notifications stopped working (possibly due to entitlement error)

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, pushkit, react-native-notifications

In the last couple of days we were getting some bug reports due to our Push Notification Feature not working anymore.

We use React Native with react-native-notifications (newest version). The build we have up in the app store is from the beginning of October and has worked just fine.

Now, out of nowhere when i press the button that is linked to requesting the PushToken, nothing happens - not even the Failure-Callback is triggered.

When i open the device console i just get these two errors when i click the button:

```
error   14:11:19.891971+0100    SpringBoard Entitlment 'com.apple.private.usernotifications.bundle-identifiers' for online.*.* required to request user notifications
error   14:11:19.892050+0100    SpringBoard [online.*.*] Requesting authorization failed because of missing entitlement
```

But obviously the entitlement for Push Notifications is set (and always has been).

Any of you got any ideas what to check? I'm a bit clueless right now.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick heads-up. Problem was, that my Product Name (Target -> Your App -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name) had german special characters.

See also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660648